# Modal not getting triggered from Materialize CSS

Tags: javascript, html

I have a small Google web-app form, that collects date and message and then passes it to a Google sheet which all works fine. On the HTML side I also want the page to be closed which is not happening.

On pressing button "Submit", I want to open the Modal, but its not working. I have little experience in HTML with JavaScript. Please explain to me what is wrong with my code and why my modal is not opening.

here is my JavaScript side:-

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

    var delems = document.querySelectorAll('.datepicker');
    var dinstances = M.Datepicker.init(delems);
    var elems1 = document.querySelectorAll('.modal');
    var instances1 = M.Modal.init(elems1);
});

document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click',doleave);

function doleave()
{  


    var singleModalElem = document.querySelector('.modal');
    var instance = M.Modal.getInstance(singleModalElem);
    instance.open();       
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example?

Comment: Hi Marco, I have made an edit. please have a look and let me know if you have any confusing.